# minutes minutes vs short minute of a meeting

Tags: disambiguities

I heard and used "meeting minutes" for quite some time but just read today somebody asking for "short minute of your conversation" (as opposed to minute**S**)
Since it looked odd, I checked [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minutes) which clearly states that "minute" (singular) can be used for a "note or a summary" (see #6 & #7)

My question is, does it *sound* normal to use "minute" to describe a summary?
For clarity, I understand that common use is minute**S**

Comment: There is a difference; #7 (when I check your AHDEL link) stipulates that the record is official. #6 (one of the count noun usages) does not stipulate this; the senses are different. What is officially recorded at a meeting is not 'memoranda' / 'notes'; often, 'minutes' are required by law. I've not come across the looser definition before.

Comment: The OP seems to be missing an important point here. The two usages are quite different and not grammatical-number cousins. *Minutes* (singular, not plural or *minute* ) is "7. **An** official record of the proceedings of a meeting," whereas *Minute* is "6. **A** note or summary covering points to be remembered; a memorandum." Once again, **both** are singular. "**A** short minute of your conversation" in the sense of a short note is fine. (all references from TFD cited by OP; emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common use *is* minutes, but you *may* hear people talking of a "minute" in the context of discussing the "minutes".

e.g.

- "Here are the minutes of yesterday's meeting"
- "Oh, thanks - let me just have a quick look....ah, yes, I see in minute XYZ that you reached agreement on blah-blah-blah...."

Although I'd say it's more usual to talk about "point so-and-so" or "paragraph so-and-so".

Comment: While the above may well be true, it does not address the 'unofficial' usage (synonym 'summary' or even 'note') OP is asking about. Your post refers to the countification of AHDEL sense #7, not AHDEL sense #6.

Comment: The OP asked "does it sound normal", which was what I was answering (subjective, I know).

Comment: No, OP asked '[D]oes it sound normal to use "minute" to describe a summary?' Immediately after referring to a dictionary definition for minute as 'summary / note' which obviously did not refer to the non-count (but plural form) usage demanding an _official_ record. Omitting an essential part of a quote is just plain wrong, not 'subjective'.